# Import js file CakePHP src tag is missing

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.7

I am trying to do something really simple which I've done a thousand times already. I am trying to import a JS file on CakePHP using the Html Helper and instead of the "src" attribute i get a `"facebook"` attribute . Here is what I am doing:-

```
echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap.min');
```

and here is the result:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" facebook="/js/bootstrap.min.js">
```

I am using a fresh install of CakePHP 2.7.6.

Comment: Do all scripts come out like this? Maybe you have some browser plugin to change src?

Answer (score 1):

Just keep you js folder in webroot directory, then it will work hopefully.

Secondly, you have written the correct syntax

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap.min'); ?>
```

third, it is also depends upon the .htaccess file. if you don't get your path correct then tell me, where you have kept your project, and what you have written in your .htaccess file.

Thanks.

Comment: It is in the webroot js. the htaccess is fine and the path is fine.

Comment: The OP's issue doesn't appear to be that the script isn't being found, but that the HTML helper is generating the wrong attribute. .htaccess and the location of the JS files should have no affect on this!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the CakePHP `HtmlHelper` or have you customised this?

If you take a look at the `HtmlHelper` you should see that it is doing a simple `sprintf()` of `$this->_tags['javascriptlink']` which is [defined on line 103](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.7/lib/Cake/View/Helper/HtmlHelper.php#L103) as:-

```
'<script type="text/javascript" src="%s"%s></script>'
```

No mention of `facebook`. Your code is clearly not doing this. So check that this tag is correctly set in the helper that you are using.

Comment: It should be only reason.

Comment: I have searched the entire code and database and there is no facebook string anywhere. Also i am using the default HtmlHelper.

Comment: I wouldn't normally recommend tinkering with core code, but it would perhaps help you debug if you attempt to check what `HtmlHelper::script()` is generating before it is returned to the view to ensure that this is being called correctly and not being altered by anything else. You should definitely *not* have `facebook` returned as an attribute. Try checking that `$out` is correctly set in the `script()` method and debug from there.